# In FFmpeg, can -filter_complex do everything that -filter can? (i.e., is it a direct replacement)

Tags: ffmpeg

This may seem like a strange question but... is it possible to do everything -filter can do using only -filter_complex filters? That is, is there anything that -filter can do, that is not possible with -filter_complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `-filter` and `-filter_complex / -lavfi` both set up a filtergraph. The difference is that the latter can be fed with multiple inputs and can supply multiple outputs. `-filter` is limited to one input and one output stream. There is a hack to introduce additional inputs in `-filter` using source filters but that is not advised. All filters that can be used in `-filter` can be used in `-filter_complex`.

Note that if you specify filtering for a conditionally mapped stream (`-map 0:a:1?`), and that stream does not exist, the command will proceed with `-filter` but not with `-filter_complex`.

Comment: Very interesting, not clear from FFmpeg docs. So why was -filter not deprecated?

Comment: -filter is still useful and there's no reason for it to be deprecated. For many common use cases, a simple filterchain suffices.

Comment: Is there any reason that conditional streams aren't supported by `-filter_complex`?

Comment: In a complex graph, filter outputs (and inputs) can interact with each other e.g. blend. So, it's not straightforward to redraw a graph where some inputs are missing. Can be done in a limited manner, in principle, but the logic would be convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

No, -filter_complex is not a substitute for -filter.  [Specifically](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9649):

> The point of -filter_complex is that there is no 1:1 map between input
> and output. Therefore there is no map to decide which metadata to
> copy.

Moreover, there is no simple workaround to this limitation.  To preserve per-stream metadata, use -filter whenever possible.  With -filter_complex, stream metadata would have to be mapped manually for all streams in the output file (using 1 -map_metadata:s per stream).

Comment: Upvoted because this is an enlightening answer, but it would make more sense to restate the first line, which is confusing - the real answer seems to be that it *is mostly* a substitute for `-filter`, except in the case of the one caveat that you've come across, and the one that Gyan mentions in his answer.